# jQuery on click trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with my jQuery on click function. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong since it isn't even registering the click in the console (I have set breakpoints and it refuses to visit my on click). I am using jQuery in other areas of my code, so I think I have linked it correctly, and I have checked the target several times to make sure that it is a class and I'm using the correct syntax, but I must have missed something. I feel like I have just been looking at it too long. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<h3 class="collapseButton leftH3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse_me">
    Returns information about the current User 
    <span class="pull-right" id="arrow_me">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</h3>
```

JS:

```
function changeArrows() {
    $('.collapseButton').on("click", function() {
        $(this).next('.pull-right')
          .html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    });
}
changeArrows();
```

Comment: `$(this)` resolves to be the `h3` element the way you've written the event handler. `.next` finds the very next sibling with the given selector, and not the child. That should get you on your way.

Comment: Are you including your JS at the bottom of the page so it executes after jQuery and the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Zack , My jQuery is right above my js.

Comment: you are putting your event handler code inside changeArrows function, but you are not calling it anywhere in the code, hence the click event is not  registerd with the jquery event queue

Comment: @atul "you are not calling it anywhere in the code", it is called immediately after its definition...

Comment: oh sorry i missed that :(

Comment: Is the Javascript before or after the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `children` not `next`

```
function changeArrows() {
    $('.collapseButton').on("click", function() {
       $(this).children('.pull-right')
           .html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked. I just can't accept your answer for a few more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The on click is triggert but your selecotor is not correct.

`$(this).children('.pull-right').html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');`

works fine for me (changed next for children)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 changeArrows();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, rewrote it to do what you want it to do. Note that instead of `next()` (which gets the following *sibling* element with the given selector), you want `children()` (which gets the *child* elements of `$(this)`).

`$(this)` ends up resolving to be the `h3` element in almost every case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapseButton').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).children('.pull-right')
      .html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the body of your function in `$(document).ready( ... )`. I don't think your event handler is available after this function is run. The .next() will also find the next sibling, but the element you're wanting to change is a child.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapseButton').on("click", function() {
    $(this).children('.fa.fa-arrow-up')
       .html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just toggle the class for the `i` element without changing `html`:

```
$(".collapseButton").click(function(e) {
$(this).children('.pull-right').children('.fa-arrow-down').toggleClass('fa-arrow-up');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setVisibility(id1,id2,id3) {
if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Show Box 3'){
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Box 4';
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Box 5';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none';
}else{
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Box 3';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'inline';
}
}
```

```html
<h4 class="pro_detail_title_name_new" >Product Description
<button type=button name=type id='bt1' onclick="setVisibility('sub3','sub4','sub5');";><span id="sub3" class="mobile-plus1"style="display:inline;" >+ </span><span id="sub5" class="fbutton"style="display:none;">-</span> </button></h4>

<div id="sub4"style="display:none;">-- inside --</div>
```